# How to count number of times that a variable become between two values?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just started to learn Java, And I'm working on my first App. I coded but the problem is when the variable changes its value in an interval the Counter increases. But my aim is if the variable "X" became compromised between "A" and "B" the "Counter" count one and stop adding even if "X" still varing between "A" and "B".

```
 public void update(final Counter count) {
        if(count.getWeight()<80 && count.getWeight()> 50){
            Rcount++;
            textView.setText(" Number of big Boxs "+ Rcount );
        }
 }
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. Can you post your code? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look into short-circut evalutation, it allows you to specify 2 conditions for 1 if statement, which sounds like what you need.

Comment: Thank u Mr @Robert I have just added my code.

Comment: Mr @VinceEmigh . Excuse me but how can I do it? and what is short-cuircuting conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to do. But your first line should probably look like this:

```
if(80 > count.getWeight() && count.getWeight() > 50){
```

Comment: Good, I corrected it. But the value of count.getWeight() continuous, still changing that what let Rcount change continuously also.

Comment: @JoeBa Like I said, I have no idea what you're saying. You'll have to add a lot more context if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is see if a value (I'll call it x) is between another two values (I'll call them a & b), and you want to add to another variable (I'll call it count) and print it. One way of writing the code for that would be:

```
if(x < a && x > b || x > a && x < b) {
count++;
System.out.println("Count value:" + count);
}
```

if that wasn't what you were asking I'm sorry, but I wasn't completely sure what you meant.

Comment: Thanks you sir, But what I want is the counter still invariable even if X changes its value in this interval. And when X exit from this interval and enter for the second time; then the count must increase to 2.